# How API gateway validates access token via introspection

Tags: api, security, authentication, jwt, microservices

I found one interesting article that has this illustration:

[image]

It says that:

> API Gateway verifies access token for all incoming requests via introspection

But what does this mean?

it says that gateway goes to authorization server and validates token (JWT). 
why is that needed?

if gateway has authorization server's public key, it can check token validity using signature just like every backend service, why is introspection needed and how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Identity provider it can be done either way but there are trade offs.

If you validate the token locally then yes it can use public keys to do that and that's very efficient way, however downside is that if the token or signing keys are revoked then your token is still valid. With Remote check you have to bear the http overhead but that is more reliable.

Normally tokens are kept short lived and validated locally. But if your access token are long lived, your application require strict access controls or library doesn't support local validation then it's a good idea to check them remotely

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking at [this document](https://dzone.com/articles/oauth2-tips-token-validation).

What I understood from this Secure API Gateway is that the gateway is responsible for [introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) and the back-end services will only check the token signature, which is less secure than introspection, but still a layer of security.

Introspection is necessary to validate the token information against the [Authorization Server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1).
This is more secure, because the system can ensure that the token received is not malicious, expired and it is from an known source.
The details on how it is done are explained in [RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662).

Yes, the gateway could validate the token signature if it has access to the certificate.
I can't really tell why they choose the back-end server to do it, probably a project decision.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway primarily meant for routing the incoming calls to the corresponding MicroService Clusters.

In addition to that,it can also play a role to validate the token, so that only valid traffic is routed to the downstream servers (filtering malicious traffic).

The level of validation could be up to the product owner/architect decision. It could be as simple as validating against the list of in memory cached token or in depth validation on set of claims, digital signature verification, expiry time, audience claim etc.

You can view the set of claims inside the token using JWT decoder like https://devtoolzone.com/decoder/jwt